# What if there is a missing point discontinuity at a point that could have been the global maxima?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

If the question asks me to find the global maxima of a given curve but there is a missing point discontinuity at the point that could have been the global maxima if the function was continuous at that point. Then,
[image]
where is the global maxima provided there are other local maximas too.

Comment: What is your definition of global maximum?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  The pictured function does not have a global maximum.  It has a supremum (least upper bound) but that value is never attained.